# What are breakpoints at the look-up-table in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink

I don't understand what are breakpoints when using the look-up-table in Simulink/Matlab. For example, I have a table data, which is 50 columns and 5 rows. So I am using a 2D Look-up-table, at the "table data" I wrote the name of the table, but I don't know what should I put in "Breakpoints 1" and "Breakpoints 2"? Which option should I select in "Breakpoints specification"?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/2dlookuptable.html

Comment: Yes, I have read it. I still don't understand what means "Specifies a breakpoint vector that corresponds to each dimension of your lookup table."? So for 50 data in the table (columns) I write [1:50]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt to explain this for you. I know its an old post but I had trouble understanding it previously too, so I hope it helps someone.

Imagine you want to create a lookup table where:

```
X = f(Y, Z)
```

As an example lets say it is very simple addition:

```
X = Y + Z
```

So if `Y = 1` and `Z = 2`, `X = 1 + 2 = 3`

Now we can create lookup table for X.
If you read about the breakpoints in the documentation of lookuptables in Simulink

> "Values: 1-by-n or n-by-1 vector of monotonically increasing values"
>   Meaning that Y and Z need to be monotonically increasing

So lets say we want to make a 2-D lookup table for when:

```
Y = [1 2 3] and Z = [4 5 6]  <------ These are your breakpoints
```

Then the lookup table will look as follows:

```
      4 5 6 <---- Z breakpoints

1     5 6 7
2     6 7 8  <---- X table; X = f(Y, Z); X = Y + Z in this case
3     7 8 9
^
Y breakpoints
```